# How do I handle a simple Alert using C# and Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, alert

This is my code, when it gets to `Switchto().Alert()` there is an error saying 'No such alert'

```
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Add Document'])[1]/following::button[1]")).Click();

            **driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();**

            var signFrame = driver.FindElement(By.Id("hsEmbeddedFrame"));
            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(signFrame);


            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Istrong textnitials'])[1]/preceding::li[1]")).Click();strong text
```

Answer (score 4):

You may need to wait for the alert to exist before clicking on it:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

// alert is present will automatically switch to the alert
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());

// the below line is no longer necessary
// driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

If this still throws `NoSuchAlertException`, then the popup appearing may not truly be an alert, but possibly an HTML modal instead -- in which case, you can inspect it & use Selenium to find an appropriate selector to accept it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. _ExpectedConditions_ as `AlertIsPresent()` does includes _switching to the alert_. You don't have to `driver.SwitchTo().Alert()` again.

Comment: Updated as needed!